# How to combined Oscillators to work in tandem?

Tags: pine-script

can someone give me an example how I can combine a couple different oscillators on in 1 indicator.  Example Stoch RSI, Money Flow Index, Vwap into 1 to avoid 3-4 oscillator windows.  Im new any help is much appreciated.  thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code you have already written to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

fastreg,

The first thing to do is to add the scripts that you are interested in to Trading View. Then click on the { } view source code function (which is next to the title of the script on the left hand side). This will then allow you to see how the script is configured. For example MFI and Stoch RSI use the same scale so you can copy and paste the scripts into one as below. But the VWAP is against the scale of the symbol you are displaying so you would not be able to add that into the below as the scale would be off.

For future submissions try and provide as much info as possible even if its just links to the scripts you are interested in using/changing.

Hope the below helps
Daniel

```
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic RSI+MFI", shorttitle="Stoch RSI+MFI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
smoothK = input(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = sma(stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#0094FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6A00)

//MFI
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14, minval=1, maxval=2000)
srcmfi = hlc3
upper = sum(volume * (change(srcmfi) <= 0 ? 0 : srcmfi), length)
lower = sum(volume * (change(srcmfi) >= 0 ? 0 : srcmfi), length)
_rsi(upper, lower) =>
    if lower == 0
        100
    if upper == 0
        0
    100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + upper / lower))
mf = _rsi(upper, lower)
plot(mf, "MF", color=#459915)

h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#606060)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#606060)
fill(h0, h1, color=#9915FF, transp=80, title="Background")
```